# Merge All UI Events to one Observable, but i only receive the last merged event

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-binding

I am trying to merge all UI events in one Observable, so i can react to all events, such as: onCreate life cycle, scroll Events from my RecyclerView, searchEvents from search view and deleteEvents from Action mode activation. I am using Rxbinding to achieve this. I am trying to implement Redux pattern from Jake Wharton's presentation: http://jakewharton.com/the-state-of-managing-state-with-rxjava/

Actual Result: only the GetUsersEvent gets fired, while other events do not.

Expected Result: All events get fired when appropriate.

Thanks in advance.
My Code:

```
public Observable events; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    events = Observable.just(new GetUsersEvent());
    //... boiler plate
    events.mergeWith(RxRecyclerView.scrollEvents(userRecycler).map(recyclerViewScrollEvent -> {
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if ((layoutManager.getChildCount() + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0 && totalItemCount >= PAGE_SIZE) {
            uiModel = new UserListState.Builder(uiModel)
                    .setUsers(uiModel.getUsers())
                    .setYScroll(firstVisibleItemPosition)
                    .build();
            return new UsersNextPageEvent(uiModel.getLastId());
        }
        return null;
    }));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.selected_list_menu, menu);
    events.mergeWith(RxMenuItem.clicks(menu.findItem(R.id.delete_item))
            .map(click -> new DeleteUsersEvent(usersAdapter.getSelectedItemsIds())));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    events.mergeWith(RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(mSearchView)
            .map(query -> new SearchUsersEvent(query.toString()))
            .doOnNext(searchUsersEvent -> Log.d("searchEvent", "eventFired")));
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    events.compose(userListVM.uiModels(mapEventsToActions, mapActionsToExecutables, stateReducer,
            DeleteUsersEvent.class, GetUsersEvent.class, SearchUsersEvent.class, UsersNextPageEvent.class))
            .compose(bindToLifecycle()).subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<>(this, ERROR_WITH_RETRY));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a ton of `events.mergeWith(...)`, but what are you doing with the results? That operation gives you a new observable.

You could do `events = events.mergeWith(...)`.

Comment: Your solution works fine, but it does not work for the case of the  "onCreateActionMode", do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: That's because `onCreateActionMode` is called *after* onResume. You need an event bus.